# Terraform - Creating resources in one transaction / setting rollback policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I'm using Terraform with AWS as a provider.

In one of my networks I accidentally configured wrong values which led to 
failure in resources creation.

So the situation was that some parts of the resources were up and running,
but I would prefer that the all process was executed as **one transaction**.

I'm familiar with the output the Terraform gives in such cases:

> Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
>   Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with any
>   resources that successfully completed. Please address the error above
>   and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.

**My question is:** *Is there still a way to **setup a rollback policy** in cases that some resources where created and some failed?*

Below is a simple example to reproduce the problem.

In the local variable `'az_list'` just the change value from 'names' to 'zone_ids':

```
az_list = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids}"
```

And a VPC will be created with some default security groups and Route tables but without subnets.

---

resources.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
}

### Local data ###
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

locals {
  #In order to reproduce an error: Change 'names' to 'zone_ids'
  az_list = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names}"  
}

### Vpc ###
resource "aws_vpc" "base_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "${var.cidr}"
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_hostnames = "false"
  enable_dns_support   = "true"
}

### Subnets ###
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.base_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet( var.cidr, 8, count.index + 1 + length(local.az_list) )}"
  availability_zone = "${element(local.az_list, count.index)}"
  count             = 2
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.base_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(var.cidr, 8, count.index + 1)}"
  availability_zone = "${element(local.az_list, count.index)}"
  count             = 2
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "region" {
  description = "Name of region"
  default     = "ap-south-1"
}


variable "cidr" {
  description = "The CIDR block for the VPC"
  default     = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

Comment: as the statement, `Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors`. You can only destroy the whole stack, or move on to apply the whole stack.

Comment: There are some ways to fix issues with wrong tfstate files with `terraform state rm`, but that need some manual tasks involved.

Comment: Is there a way to output the status code in those cases (to be served to external script)?

Comment: Why would you want to roll it back to destroy the VPC instead of just fixing the error and then applying out the subnets alone? A partial apply seems more useful here

Comment: In some cases a partial apply will be useful, maybe in many cases, but in some automation processes I would prefer that the all creation will be rolled back.

Comment: then, will `terraform destroy` help or not? So you can write a wrapper script, if apply doesn't run properly, destroy the whole stack

Comment: Yeap, if no other solution available - I'll have to do it like this.